# Create a board made of Cells able host a Generic value

Tags: java, generics, class-design

I'm working on a project(*a game*) which will have a board to play on.

I want to make this board as generic as possible in order to be able to re-use the code for a possible other game.

```
public class Board {
    private int rows;
    private int cols;
    private Box[][] board;

    public Board(int rows, int cols){
        Box[][] board = new Box[rows][cols];
        for (int row = 0; row < this.rows; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < this.cols; col++){
                board[row][col] = new Box();
            }
        }
    }

    public int getCols(){return this.cols;}
    public int getRows(){return this.rows;}

    public Piece getContentAtPos(int row, int col){
        return board[row][col].getContent();
    }
}
```

This is the `Board` class. The problem here is that I have to return a `Piece` object with the `getContentAtPos()` method because the `Box` (*Cell*) class is like this:

```
public class Box {
    private boolean empty;
    private Piece content;

    public Box(){
        empty = true;
    }

    public Box(Piece piece){
        empty = false;
        this.content = piece;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return empty;
    }

    public Piece getContent(){
        if (!empty) {
            return content;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas, the ideal for me would be the class `Box` to be able to host any type of object and return this generic object with `getContentAtPos()` via the Box `getContent()` method.

My generic `Box` class.

```
public class Box<T>{
    private boolean empty;
    private T content;

    public Box(){
        empty = true;
    }

    public Box(T content){
        this.content = content;
        empty = false;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return empty;
    }

    public T getContent(){
        if (!isEmpty()){
            return content;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public T setContent(Object content){
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

But what do I need to change in the Board class?

What return value shall I put there?

Comment: Do you mean to define your class as `Box<T>` and the method as `pubilc T getContent`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but the getContentAtPos method says the type is not compatible

Comment: If you want to have multiple distinct types of pieces, then the boxes must be defined to be capable hold the common supertype of all these types, and that is also the most specific type you can get out of them afterwards. You may also want to read about runtime vs. compile time type - generics are a compile time feature in java, and cannot take runtime types into account.

Comment: Please post your generic solution. If your class member is defined as `T content` (as well as the constructor parameter) it should work.

Comment: I posted my generic Box class, my problem is: I don't know what return type the Board class getContentAtPos should have

Comment: `public T setContent(Object content){` should be ``public void setContent(T content){``

Comment: Well, there you stumbled on another relic of early history of Java - arrays don't work with generics. You can either use an ArrayList, or create an intermediate type that is not generic.

Comment: The member must be defined as `private Box<Piece>[][] board;`

Comment: @StefanWarminski that does not help - such an array cannot be instantiated.

Comment: @Hulk I never would recomment to use arrays but `List<String>[][] l = new List[1][1]; List<String> list = l[0][0];` works fine for me

Comment: excuse me but the Array contains only Box types. the only thing I'd need to be of generic type is the content of the box.

Comment: @StefanWarminski only because generics are discarded due to the rawtype `new List[1][1];` (unchecked conversion warning in eclipse)

Comment: maybe I misinterpreted the meaning of <T>

Comment: @bogus this is probably the core of the misunderstanding: a `Box<T>` means that you can create a `Box<A>` and a `Box<B>`, and the first is capable of holding an `A`, while the second can hold a `B`. But they are not the same type. If you want to have both in the same list, you need a common supertype, like `Box<?>` - a *wildcard*. And if you want to get them out again, you only know that you have a `Box<?>`, you no longer know if it was a `Box<A>` or a `Box<B>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the ideal for me would be the class `Box` to be able to host ***any type*** of
> object and return this generic object with `getContentAtPos` via the `Box`
> `getContent` method

I guess you expect your game pieces to declare a certain behavior. If so, `Box` doesn't need to store an arbitrary object, but an object of type representing a contract that encompass all the methods which a game piece is expected to have.

In other words, you can define an interface, let's say `Piece`, which will have several implementations:

```
public interface Piece {
    // behavior of game pieces
}

public class MyGamePiece implements Piece {
    // implementations
}
```

You don't need to make `Box` class to be generic, instead it can contain a field of type `Piece`:

```
public class Box {
    private boolean empty;
    private Piece content;
    
    // constractor and methods

    public void setContent(Object content){
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Piece getContent(){
        return content;
    }
}
```

That gives you a freedom to provide any implementation of the `Peice` via constructor of the `Box` class or true the setter. It means you can design the core part of the gave having only one implementation `MyGamePiece`, and later on add a few more classes like `NewGamePeace` (names should reflect the purpose of the class if the clear and concise way, it's just dummy example).

The key point is that you can benefit from the [*polymorphism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) and don't have to change the previously designed and tested code in order to make it work with new classes (that called a *late binding*):

```
Box box = new Box();
box.setContent(new MyGamePiece());
box.setContent(new NewGamePeace()); // in order to make this line compile only need to introde the `NewGamePeace` class itself
```

And method `getContentAtPos()` will also return an object of type `Piece`.

> I want to make this board as generic as possible in order to be able
> to re-use the code for a possible other game.

That's a laudable aim.

Your classes have to be [loosely coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Low_coupling) and [narrow focused](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#High_cohesion) in order to be reusable. I.e. each class should a narrow and well-defined set of functionality and be aware only of those object that are crucial for it work (reduce coupling).

And you can make the necessary coupling loose (*high coupling isn't good, but classes can't interact without coupling at all, you need to maintain balance*) by introducing interfaces as shown above.

Even if eventually you would not use this code in other project, keeping it loosely coupled is beneficial because it makes it easier to maintain and expand the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should create interface that every class you will return in the future will implement. This way you will be sure that return type will implement interface and have defined behaviour.

```
    public interface ReturnableBox { 
          public boolean isEmpty();
    }
    public class Board {

       private int rows;
       private int cols;
       private ReturnableBox [][] board;
   }
   public class Box implements ReturnableBox {
   //...
   }
```